# Symfony2 Entity type form with name and image

Tags: symfony

I have an entity with both a name (string) and a file (also a string representing the filename). This is the "Icon" entity.
I have another entity called "Category" which has a name (string) and a relation to an Icon (OneToMany). I want the form to allow a user to select an Icon for a Category.

So I could display it in the form as:

```
$builder->add('icon', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'CroltsMainBundle:Icon',
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => false
));
```

But what I really want is to display something like this in twig for each radio button:

```
<div>
<label for="something"><img src="/icons/{{icon.file }}" />{{icon.name}}</label>
<input type="radio" name="something" value="{{ icon.id }}" />
</div>
```

Is there a good way to make that type of radio form with Symfony forms? Like would a custom Type be what I want? I really haven't done too much with custom types to know how much of this is possible.

Comment: Download genemu form bundle to learn and reuse stuff about custom form field because it sound it's what you need

Comment: I'm looking at a lot of custom form stuff and I'm just confused about how to access other properties of an entity from my new "EntityType"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure it is the best way but here is how I manage this kind of situation :

1. create a new formtype that behalf as `entityType`, `IconCheckType` for instance:
   (http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html)

   ```
   namespace .....\Form\Type;

   use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
   use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
   use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
   use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;


   class IconCheckType extends AbstractType
   {
      /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
     public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {

       $builder -> setAttribute('dataType', $options['dataType']);
     }

      /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
     public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form) {
       $view -> set('dataType', $form -> getAttribute('dataType'));
     }

      /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
     public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
       return array('required' => false,'dataType'=>'entity');
     }


     /**
        * Returns the allowed option values for each option (if any).
        *
        * @param array $options
        *
        * @return array The allowed option values
        */
       public function getAllowedOptionValues(array $options)
       {
           return array('required' => array(false));
       }

      /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
     public function getParent(array $options) {
       return 'entity';
     }

      /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
     public function getName() {
       return 'iconcheck';
     }

   }
   ```
2. in your Form

   ```
   ...
   ->add('icon', 'iconcheck', array(
           'class' => 'CroltsMainBundle:Icon',
           'property'=>'formField',
           'multiple'=>false,
           'expanded'=>true
         ))
   ...
   ```

   Note the `property=>'formField'`, that means that instead of return the `__toString` as label it will return whatever you want from the function getFormField from your entity class
3. So, in your entity class:

   ```
   class Icon {

   ....
       public function getFormField() {  
          return $this;   /* or an array with only the needed attributes */ 
       }

   ....
   }
   ```
4. then you can render your custom field

   ```
   {% block iconcheck_widget %}
      {% for child in form %}
         {% set obj=child.vars.label %}
           <div>
               <label for="something"><img src="/icons/{{obj.file }}" />{{obj.name}}</label>
               {{ form_widget(child) }} {# the radio/checkbox #}
             </div>
         {{ form_widget(child) }}#}
       {% endfor %}


   {% endblock %}
   ```

Comment: My method (see below) seemed to work but it wasn't marking the proper radio choice as "checked". Your method works with a few fixes for Sf2.1 (although I wasn't using 2.1 when I first asked the question). Anyway, thanks for the first answer that seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

Could you potentially make your `__toString()` method:

```
<?php
// Icon entity
public function __toString()
{
  return '<img src="/icons/'. $this->file .'" />' . $this->name';
}
```

If not then you will have to create a custom type. However it is really easy

```
<?php

namespace Your\NameSpace;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormViewInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class MyCustomType extends AbstractType
{
  public function getParent()
  {
    // By calling get parent here your custom type will
    // automatically inherit all the properties/functionality 
    // of the type you extend
    return 'radio';
  }
}
```

Then you can make your custom widget for your type. I would read the [cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) if I was you because it explains the process very well. You can look at the default Twig widgets for forms to learn how to write your own.

Comment: The first suggestion does not work. The string gets encoded so it can't be HTML (output is `&lt;img`...). Second answer is something I'm trying (I know how to make a new type). What I don't know is how to have it associated with two properties of an entity.

Comment: Okay, I was able to figure this one out. Though it's not a preferred solution I realized because now the location of the file is hardcoded to be in `/icons/` and that is set in the ENTITY. I could get it work by changing the label output to `{{ label|raw }}` though.

Comment: Hi Matt, sorry I didn't manage to get back to you on that one, glad you managed to come up with some kind of solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add a thumbnail in front of the select file button for image uploading today.  I wound up doing this.  Sorry I don't have time to create a complete example for your case.

- I'm only accessing the parent to get the entity to pass to the vich_uploadable_asset() helper.

/src/AcmeBundle/Form/Type/AcmeFormType.php

```
<?php
    namespace Acme\AcmeBundle\Form\Type;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

    class AcmeFormType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

            $builder
                ->add('icon', 'vich_uploadable')
            ...
```

config.yml

```
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'AcmeBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'

services:
    acme.type.vich_uploadable:
        class: Acme\AcmeBundle\Form\Type\VichUploadableFieldType
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: vich_uploadable }
```

/src/Acme/AcmeBundle/Form/fields.html.twig

```
{% block vich_uploadable_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if attribute(form.parent.vars.value, form.name) is not empty %}
    <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(form.parent.vars.value, form.name) | imagine_filter('thumb_square') }}" />
    {% endif %}
    {{ form_widget(form) }} {# If you're extending the radio button, it would show here #}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like it helps. I could add a single image like you did just fine. I need to display a list of entities with an image based on one property and the text based on another property.

Comment: I now see how the `vich_uploader_asset` is a helpful Twig function for what I'm doing. I'm partially using this solution. I will share how I put it all together.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing. It took a lot of trial and error and digging into the EntityType class hierarchy and learning how Form types really work. The hardest part is looking at source code and figuring out how to get from PHP classes to Twig templates (what variables are available).

Here is what I did. It is not a perfect solution (feels a bit hacky) but it works for my purposes. The idea is to expose the underlying Entity to my view so I can get its properties.

The biggest problem is that the `file` property which holds the file path is hardcoded in the view. Anyway, I'm posting the entire solution as it may be helpful to others. Also I'm open to critique if someone can find a better solution.

*(namespaces omitted)*

### Extended Entity Type

```
<?php
class ExtendedEntityType extends EntityType
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'extended_choice';
    }
    
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'extended_entity';
    }
}
```

### Extended Choice Type (just had to change addSubForms but it's private)

```
<?php
class ExtendedChoiceType extends ChoiceType
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if (!$options['choice_list'] && !is_array($options['choices']) && !$options['choices'] instanceof \Traversable) {
            throw new FormException('Either the option "choices" or "choice_list" must be set.');
        }

        if ($options['expanded']) {
            $this->addSubForms($builder, $options['choice_list']->getPreferredViews(), $options);
            $this->addSubForms($builder, $options['choice_list']->getRemainingViews(), $options);

            if ($options['multiple']) {
                $builder
                    ->addViewTransformer(new ChoicesToBooleanArrayTransformer($options['choice_list']))
                    ->addEventSubscriber(new FixCheckboxInputListener($options['choice_list']), 10)
                ;
            } else {
                $builder
                    ->addViewTransformer(new ChoiceToBooleanArrayTransformer($options['choice_list']))
                    ->addEventSubscriber(new FixRadioInputListener($options['choice_list']), 10)
                ;
            }
        } else {
            if ($options['multiple']) {
                $builder->addViewTransformer(new ChoicesToValuesTransformer($options['choice_list']));
            } else {
                $builder->addViewTransformer(new ChoiceToValueTransformer($options['choice_list']));
            }
        }

        if ($options['multiple'] && $options['by_reference']) {
            // Make sure the collection created during the client->norm
            // transformation is merged back into the original collection
            $builder->addEventSubscriber(new MergeCollectionListener(true, true));
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'extended_choice';
    }

    /**
     * Adds the sub fields for an expanded choice field.
     *
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder     The form builder.
     * @param array                $choiceViews The choice view objects.
     * @param array                $options     The build options.
     */
    private function addSubForms(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $choiceViews, array $options)
    {
        foreach ($choiceViews as $i => $choiceView) {
            if (is_array($choiceView)) {
                // Flatten groups
                $this->addSubForms($builder, $choiceView, $options);
            } else {
                $choiceOpts = array(
                    'value' => $choiceView->value,
                    // Expose more data
                    'label' => array(
                        'data' => $choiceView->data,
                        'label' => $choiceView->label,
                    ),
                    'translation_domain' => $options['translation_domain'],
                );

                if ($options['multiple']) {
                    $choiceType = 'checkbox';
                    // The user can check 0 or more checkboxes. If required
                    // is true, he is required to check all of them.
                    $choiceOpts['required'] = false;
                } else {
                    $choiceType = 'radio';
                }

                $builder->add((string) $i, $choiceType, $choiceOpts);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Services

```
    <service id="crolts_main.type.extended_choice" class="My\MainBundle\Form\Type\ExtendedChoiceType">
        <tag name="form.type" alias="extended_choice" />
    </service>
    
    <service id="crolts_main.type.extended_entity" class="My\MainBundle\Form\Type\ExtendedEntityType">
        <tag name="form.type" alias="extended_entity" />
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine" />
    </service>
```

### form_layout.html.twig

(this is based on MopaBootStrapBundle but the idea is the same. The difference is that MopaBootstrap wraps the `<label>` around the `<radio>`)

```
{% block extended_choice_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if expanded %}
        {{ block('extended_choice_widget_expanded') }}
    {% else %}
        {# not being used, just default #}
        {{ block('choice_widget_collapsed') }}
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock extended_choice_widget %}

{% block extended_choice_widget_expanded %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
    {% for child in form %}
        <label class="{{ (multiple ? 'checkbox' : 'radio') ~ (widget_type ? ' ' ~ widget_type : '') ~ (inline is defined and inline ? ' inline' : '') }}">
            {{ form_widget(child, {'attr': {'class': attr.widget_class|default('')}}) }}
            {% if child.vars.label.data.file is defined %}
                <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(child.vars.label.data, 'file')}}" alt="">
            {% endif %}
            {{ child.vars.label.label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}
        </label>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock extended_choice_widget_expanded %}
```

### Usage

```
<?php 
$builder->add('icon', 'extended_entity', array(
        'class' => 'MyMainBundle:MenuIcon',
        'property' => 'name', // this is still used in label.label
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => false
    ));
```